# Convert existing iOS paid app to free app with in-app purchase

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Currently I have a paid app in the App Store. But I want to update app current paid version to a freemium (with in app purchase) model, so is there any way to update paid version to freemium (in app purchase)?

Please suggest me where I need to configure iTunes Connect account, while uploading the new version on App Store.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. My Apps > App Store > Pricing and Availability > Price Schedule
2. Click "Plan a Price Change"
3. Set Price, Start Date and End Date

   - Price: 0
   - Start Date: Today
   - End Date: No End Date

[image]

4. Click "Done" button
5. Click "Save" button

It takes time for the price data to be updated.

Comment: i need to set price should be zero , and need to select  In app  purchase while uploading the app on app store, is it correct?

Comment: I think the question is not about price change, but how to enable all features for old users who have paid for the app.